# declare NOT EXIST clause in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How can i declaring "NOT EXIST" clause in CodeIgniter without using db->query?
If any function exist please say it to me, for example db->join...
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check for the table then execute this query

```
$query = $this->db->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE mytable_name");
```

It will results the tables which are with name `mytable_name` and if it does'nt exists any table then it results null.

Or simply you can try like

```
if ($this->db->table_exists('mytable_name')) {
   echo 'Table is already exists';
} else {
   CREATE table
}
```

Comment: I think he means [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)...?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such clause of "not exists" in active record. However, you can just pass your "not exist clause" in the `where` clause like this:

```
$this->db->where('NOT EXISTS ');
```